# Loading resource XML from SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-resources

i am trying to load resource from sd card but `getResource` is not accepting `getExternalStorageDirectory()` here is the what i am trying . .

```
InputStream in;
in = getResources().openRawResource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/RegInfo/output/data.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FileInputStream` to read `File` from `SDCard` as follows...

```
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/RegInfo/output/data.xml");
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
```

Comment: it says : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/RegInfo/output/data.xml (Permission denied)

Comment: these are added in manifest file ;  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: So, what is your code look like now after modification.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29): `openRawResource()` takes an int as the argument, the id of the resource.

Resources always come bundled with the app, so what you are referring to are not actually resources.

A quick search on SO will show you quite some examples on how to read data from external storage.